# laravel validation for array of array in exist validation

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to implement an API for placing order.I want validate the data with laarvel validation.The following is the sample input values which i want validate

```
  {
  "phone": "phone",
  "cart_items": [
    {
      "category_id": "1",
      "product_id": "1",
      "product_count": "1",
      "quantity": "1",
      "prize_per_unit": "1"
    },
    {
      "category_id": "2",
      "product_id": "1",
      "product_count": "1",
      "quantity": "1",
      "prize_per_unit": "1"
    }
  ],
  "total": "2",
  "net_amount": "100"
}
```

I want validate product id against products table based on product id and category id.The product table contain product_id and category id,
The following is the my validation rule.

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
            //'customer_id'=>['required','exists:users,id'],
            'phone'=>['required','max:12',function($attribute, $value, $fail) {

                $re = '/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[6789]\d{9}$/';

                if (preg_match_all($re, $value, $matches)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');


            } ],

            'cart_items.*.category_id'=>['required','exists:categories,cat_id'],
            'cart_items.*.product_id'=>['required',Rule::exists('products','product_id')->where(function($query)use ($request) {
                $query->where('category_cat_id',$request->category_id);

            })],
            'cart_items.*.product_count'=>['required','integer','max:100','min:1',''],
            'cart_items.*.quantity'=>['required','integer'],
            'cart_items.*.delivery_charge'=>['nullable','integer','min:0'],
            'cart_items.*.prize_per_unit'=>['required','integer','min:1'],
            'total'=>['required','integer','min:1'],
            'net_amount'=>['required','integer','min:1'],



        ],[
            'category_id.exists'=>'Not a valid category',
            'product_id.exists'=>'Not a valid product'

        ]);
```

My question is how to validate this rule

```
'cart_items.*.product_id'=>['required',Rule::exists('products','product_id')->where(function($query)use ($request) 
        {
                $query->where('category_cat_id',$request->category_id);
                })],
```

what will be replaced with ,`$request->category_id` which is  an array

Comment: Have you tried `whereIn` -- it accepts an array of values

Comment: how to use where in with array of array?